# Number of rows into a HDF5

Tags: python, pydev, hdf5, liclipse

there's a method for  have the number of rows of a .hdf5 without load it in ram ?

I'm using Python 3.4 with pydev on Liclipse (WIndows 10)

Thanky you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the h5py library, you can simply run `len(dataset)` or `dataset.len()` (which is recommended).

See [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html?highlight=len#length-and-iteration) for more infos.